# Bash function in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, bash

I have these functions in my .bash_profile on ubuntu server instance on google cloud for pull and push the git branch

```
plb(){
        branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
        git pull origin $branch
}
psb(){
        branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
        git push origin $branch
}
```

if i run the code line individually then the work properly but when i try to put it in a function it shows the following error

```
$ plb
 : command not found
 : command not found
```

what am i doing wrong here, thank you in advance

Output of the command:-

```
rohan@staging:~$ proj
rohan@staging:/var/www/staging/Server/www$ branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
rohan@staging:/var/www/staging/Server/www$ echo $branch
staging
rohan@staging:/var/www/staging/Server/www$ plb
 : command not found
 : command not found
rohan@staging:/var/www/staging/Server/www$
```

Comment: you need to export your functions. Try adding `export -f plb` and `export -f psb` in your .bash_profile

Comment: @Aserre added the export but it is not working still, my .bash_profile looks like this now

plb() {
        branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
        git pull origin $branch
}
psb(){
        branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
        git push origin $branch
}
export -f plb
export -f psb

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted your session?  `.bash_profile` is not re-read automatically when you modify it.  You can manually reload if by issuing a command like `. ~/.bash_profile` at the command prompt.

Functions must be loaded in memory before being called, and calling a function does not automatically causes the file where it is defined to be read (the shell does not know in which file any specific function is located anyway).  When the function is defined inside the script from which it is called, its definition must precede its use, for the same reason : the shell will not skip ahead in the script file to find a function that has not yet been defined.

Comment: yes i did restarted the session, also i made sure that i am on the correct directory where project folder is located.

Comment: What could be wrong?  Are you 100% your `.bash_profile` is in the right place (your user home directory) and actually gets sourced (not executed as a separate process)?  Are your sure it does not exit before reaching your function definitions?  Are you sure Bash is the shell used, and is not launched with an option that would prevent `.bash_profile` from being loaded?

Comment: i have other commands in .bash_profile they work properly like
`alias ..="cd .."`
its only the function that is not getting executed.

Comment: Are your functions called from another script, or at the command line?  I think by default, functions are not inherited by sub-processes.